# How to open Gmail application with value of email sent from my application and aumatically filled in gmail?

Tags: android, email

I am creating an application in which on viewing someone's profile i want to take the user to email after clicking a floating action bar

i can open gmail but i dont have email value filled already despite of sending its value

code:

```
fabtoemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String aEmail = email;
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmail);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select Application"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you should add an explanation stating why/how it solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just thought those lines didnt need explanation, but I guess that this is not the place to think like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","example@example.com", null));
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your subject here");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "if you want append some text");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```